# What word means "make something desirable"?

Tags: single-word-requests

The word "necessitate" means "make something necessary". For instance:

> The explosion necessitated installing a new kitchen.

Is there an equivalent word to mean "make something desirable (but not necessarily necessary)"? For instance:

> The ordeal [made desirable] a week off work.

Comment: Going through a family ordeal and taking a couple of days off work, for many would be a necessity. I would add another example sentence if I were you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get closer with warrants:

> The ordeal warrants a week off work.

Though that is more deserves than desires.

From the way the sentence is structured I don't believe an emotional appeal can be made in it, as something like:

> The ordeal allures a week off work.

Sounds rather forced, and can be confused to mean things like:

> The ordeal desires a week off work.

I don't believe you're looking for the ordeal itself to pack some bags and go on holiday.

From my perspective you get more flexibility by rearranging your sentence:

> The ordeal made a week off work *adjective*

Where *adjective* could be many things: desirable, inviting, enticing, and many others

Answer (score 1):

The most accurate verb for this is [**endear**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/endear):

> [Merriam-Webster]
>   **1** : to cause to become beloved or admired
>   // her generosity has *endeared* her to the public

Although it's use would be a bit strange with the example sentence, a slight paraphrase would make it more normal:

> The explosion *endeared* in them the idea of installing a new kitchen.

---

In the right context, the example sentence could be interpreted as being not a matter of necessity but desire.

For instance, the explosion damaged the living room, requiring its renovation, but didn't touch the kitchen. Although there is no need to install a new kitchen, the fact that they had to renovate *other* parts of the house, led them to desire the renovation of this part of the house too.

Of course, a more natural version of this might be:

> Renovations to other parts of the house *endeared* in them the idea of installing a new kitchen.

Answer (score 1):

The verb *beckon* comes to mind

> intransitive verb
>
> 1 : to summon or signal typically with a wave or nod
>
> My master beckons. He … beckoned to the other generals to come and stand where
>   he stood. — H. E. Scudder
>
> 2 : to appear inviting : ATTRACT
>
> the frontier beckons
>
> transitive verb
>
> : to beckon to beckoned us over to their table